# Updating GUI Popup Menu in Seperate Callback Function

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback

I am writing a basic programme that can output a number of different signals (sin, sawtooth, etc) and vary them using mutliple sliders. I cannot get the dropdown menu to update.
I am using 'updateAll', so that all sliders dropdowns, etc update the graph simultaneously when used.

Thanks in advance!

```
function popChoice_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
contents = cellstr(get(hObject,'String'));
popChoice = contents(get(hObject,'Value'));
if (strcmp(popChoice,'Sine'))
    popVal = 1;
elseif (strcmp(popChoice,'Square'))
    popVal = 2;
elseif (strcmp(popChoice,'Sawtooth'))
    popVal = 3;
elseif (strcmp(popChoice,'Triangular'))
    popVal = 4;
end
assignin('base','popVal',popVal)
updateAll()
%%Some other unrelated coder (sliders, etc) is between these functions
function updateAll 
f=round(getappdata(0,'f'));
S_rate=round(getappdata(0,'S_rate'));
t=round(getappdata(0,'t'));
phi=round(getappdata(0,'phi'));
popVal = getappdata(0,'popVal');
if popVal == 1
    Sin_Wave(f,phi,S_rate,t)
elseif popVal == 2
    Square_Wave(f,phi,S_rate,t)
elseif popVal == 3
    Sawtooth_Wave(f,phi,S_rate,t)
elseif popVal == 4
    Triangle_Wave(f,phi,S_rate,t)
end
```